# Accessing the main HTML doc in a web page for automating Chrome with Selenium

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would to automate a CSV downloading by clicking a certain sequence of buttons and links in a certain web page in my company.

However, this webpage don't have an explicit HTML elements by viewing page source code; it shows something like:

```html
<HTML ><head><title></title>
<script language="javascript" src="23048/scripts/swecommon.js?_scb="></script> 
<script language="javascript" src="23048/scripts/swecmn_hi.js?_scb="></script> 
</head><body leftmargin="8" topmargin="2" marginwidth="20" marginheight="2" class="ScreenBack"><script>
if(typeof(window._swescript)!='undefined'&&window._swescript!=null) window._swescript.InitFrame(this);</script>
<h1><span class="AppletTitle">Session Warning Message</span></h1><h4><span class="error">You have initiated a Siebel session while another Siebel session is currently active. Please choose the option that applies to you.</span></h4><ul><li><span class="error">You already have a Siebel session with unsaved data running in another browser window. To save data from a second session go to the already open session and either save and exit or continue to use that data.</span></li><li><span class="error">You do not have unsaved data in your other session and wish to close it and launch a new session.&nbsp;</span><span class="error">Click&nbsp;</span><a href='JavaScript:void(0)' onclick='SWEClearHistoryGotoURL ("start.swe?SWENeedContext=false&SWECmd=Logoff&SWEC=14&SWEBID=-1&SRN=&SWETS="); return false;'  target="_top" id='s_swepi_2'>here</a></li><li><span class="error">You have closed your previous Siebel browser instance using the Close instead of the Logoff feature and wish to open a new Siebel session.&nbsp;</span><span class="error">Click&nbsp;</span><a href='JavaScript:void(0)' onclick='SWEClearHistoryGotoURL ("start.swe?SWENeedContext=false&SWECmd=Logoff&SWEC=14&SWEBID=-1&SRN=&SWETS="); return false;'  target="_top" id='s_swepi_2'>here</a><script>

trackChange("");
SWEIsHighInteract = true; Top().SWEIsHighInteract = true;
if (typeof(window._samePage) != 'undefined' && window._samePage!="") window._samePage = "";
if (top.opener == null || typeof top.opener.swetop == 'unknown' || typeof top.opener.swetop == 'undefined') top.SiebelApp.S_App.SWECount = 14;
else top.opener.top.SiebelApp.S_App.SWECount = 14;
g_bInitialized = true;
</script>
</li></ul>
```

But, when I try to inspect a link or a button it shows an HTML doc which I think I can parse it by the Selenium methods.

The code in VBA does not work for this weird webpage and it works well with a simple webpage like Facebook:

```
Sub TestSelenium()
    Dim ChDriver As New webdriver
    ChDriver.Start "Chrome"
    ChDriver.get "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=83.0.4103.39/"
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    Stop
    ChDriver.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/a").Click
    Stop
End Sub
```

Thanks advance.

Comment: The link has no CSV files or you mean the link is different? Provide with the link so as to have look.

Comment: inspect source is different than page source because javascript is updating the DOM.  When you view page source, it shows you the DOM before the script runs.... not necessarily the current DOM.  Use webdriverwaits to wait for JS updated elements.

Comment: - Thanks Yasser; threre is no defined link for the CSV file, the element is `<a>` and when I inspect the `href` is equal to `"JavaScript:void(0)"`, It's dynamically generated I think.
- Thanks pcalkins; even I wait for loading the page I must inspect the element to get the DOM in the Chrome inspection panel.

Comment: you simply need to click that a tag (positional match) with your automation or use executeScript (sp?) method of driver to directly fire the onclick associated function.

Comment: I can't see in your image which element you need to click for the csv download. Please add your html using snippet tool via [edit] and make clear which element needs to be clicked. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks QHarr; the source view of the apparent web page (Ctrl+U) doesn't show the element I want to automate, it gives a HTML like inserted above in my question; but I try to inspect the button which it downloads the CSV, it shows the HTML with the rights elements in that web page and I can make my bot click on them I think. Sorry, my English is not well for explaining ^^'